# Print sorted list of dependencies for all projects in Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I want to create a complete list of dependencies for all projects in my Gradle build to track changes over time.

For this purpose, both the list of projects and the list of all dependencies (direct and transitive) must be sorted. Without both, the diff between releases is useless.

My first attempt was

```
fun listDependencies(project: Project, configName: String) {
    val config = project.configurations.findByName(configName) ?: return

    println()
    println("$configName of module ${project.name}:")

    config.allDependencies.map {
        "  ${it.group}:${it.name}:${it.version}"
    }.sorted().forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}

fun listDependencies(project: Project) {
    listDependencies(project, "compileClasspath")
    listDependencies(project, "testCompileClasspath")
}

/** Create sorted list of dependencies per module and only for the compileClasspath and testCompileClasspath */
task("listDependencies") {
    doLast {
        println("Dependency list per project")
        allprojects.sortedBy { it.name }
            .forEach {
                listDependencies(it)
            }
    }
}
```

In the output, most versions are `null` and all transitive dependencies are missing.

I had to force dependency resolution by changing the `config.allDependencies` above to

```
    config.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.map {
        "  ${it.moduleVersion}"
    }.sorted().forEach {
        println(it)
    }
```

This works but gives me a warning that I shouldn't call `resolvedConfiguration` ([Resolving unsafe configuration resolution errors](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sub:resolving-unsafe-configuration-resolution-errors)).

What do I have to change to run this task once after the configuration phase only when I ask for it by running Gradle with `./gradlew listDependencies`?

We don't need this task in every build.